# Material opacity not working

Tags: texturing, materials, normal-map

I'm trying to use a texture and maps for a chain-link fence, nut for some reason when I try to use opacity it makes the whole thing turn black
[image: node editor layout of my material]

this is what mine looks like

[image: an almost entirely black material preview sphere]

and this is what it should look like
[image: a material preview sphere with a chain-link fence material]

I got the maps from here: https://3dtextures.me/2019/10/01/metal-fence-001/

no matter what i do it won't change

Comment: If you are using EEVEE, make sure the material's Blend Mode is set to something other than _opaque_

Comment: Your alpha on the Principled BSDF is set to zero.

Answer (score -1):

What render engine are you using? Are you rendering on the GPU?

If you are using EEVEE, check the blend method of the material: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode

If you are using Cycles and are rendering on the GPU, try rendering on the CPU. It may be a GPU driver problem.

If the problem still persists, call your mom. :-)